# How to store pieces of Linq expression in variables and use those variables in a query?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-expressions

I have an expression like this:

```
List<BAL.Receipt> ac = BAL.ApplicationInfo.db.Receipts.Where
                (x => x.InvoiceNo.StartsWith(txtSearch.Text)
                 | x.Alias.StartsWith(txtSearch.Text)
```

What I want to do is split this expression into parts and store them in variables

Like

```
var a = x => x.InvoiceNo.StartsWith(txtSearch.Text);
var b = x => x.Alias.StartsWIth (txtSearch.Text) ;
```

When query

```
List<BAL.Receipt> ac = BAL.ApplicationInfo.db.Receipts.Where( a & b) ;
```

Is it possible to achieve this?

If possible, please show me an example.

Comment: Look into System.Reflection for run-time evaluation.  I think you will essentially have to have this code compiled and evaluated at run-time to make it happen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
Expression<Func<BAL.Receipt, bool>> a =
    x => x.InvoiceNo.StartsWith(txtSearch.Text);

Expression<Func<BAL.Receipt, bool>> b =
    x => x.Alias.StartsWIth(txtSearch.Text);

List<BAL.Receipt> ac =
    BAL.ApplicationInfo.db.Receipts
        .Where(a)
        .Where(b);
```

Comment: Was just writing the same ... here are the links I wanted to post: [quick tutorial on code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/235860/Expression-Tree-Basics) & [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) documentation on expression trees.